# submitting the form after clicking the item on the tab menu in Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

The example at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/, I would like the form is submitted when clicking the tab-2 menu.

The following is my code. However, the form doesn't submit after clicking.

Can anyone help me? Many thanks!

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

        $('#tabs-2').click(function() {
            $('#target').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <form id="target">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab-3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs-2').click(function() {
        $('#target').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yea this should work the problem with your original example is that you don't ever call your function that's inside the <script> tags.  If you use this then the event is bound to the DOM after the page loads and the event will work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that the tab plugin is preventing the default actions of the click anyway and not calling your click event.

You should try hooking into `tabselect` event instead and use `ui.tab` to check if the selected tab's `href` attribute is `#tabs-2`.

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.tab.attr('href') == '#tabs-2') {
        $('#target').submit();
    }
});
```

**Or** you could do this when you create the tabs instead:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.tab.attr('href') == '#tabs-2') {
            $('#target').submit();
        }
     }
});
```

You could also use `ui.index` to get the zero-basde index of the selected tab, or `ui.panel` to get the selected content div for that tab. Whichever you prefer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define id for Tab-2 as mentioned here. but here you are referring div id click.

```
<li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tab2">Tab-2</a></li>

$('#tabs2').click(function() {
    $('#target').submit();
});
```